# How to upgrade Eclipse to 3.8 version?

Tags: eclipse, updates

Currently i am running Eclipse 3.6 with ADT and Android plugins. Now i want to update this Android Eclipse to 3.8 version. For that, i have change the two things in the preferences in Eclipse:

1. The Eclipse Project Updates : http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8
2. Juno : http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8-201206081200/

   But the issue is while downloading, it is not able to download the all files and showing download errors.

So, is there any way to update my eclipse from 3.6 to 3.8??

Thanks..

Comment: Just a guess: try to update to 3.7 first.

Comment: Not reliable..Actually for BlackBerry 10 Android Run time they are asking for eclipse 3.8.

Comment: Don't.  Download Eclipse 3.8 to a new directory, add your plug-ins one at a time, testing to make sure Eclipse still works.  When you've added all the plug-ins, zip up your Android Eclipse so you can restore it if something happens.

Comment: "add your plug-ins one at a time, testing to make sure Eclipse still works"--What it means??

Comment: Install one plug-in.  Test to make sure Eclipse starts without crashing.  Repeat until all plug-ins are installed.